# How to make a list formatter in TiddlyWiki

Tags: javascript, html, tiddlywiki

I am working with a TiddlyWiki, and I want to make a custom formatter for a list. Basically I have an html tag called `popuplist` and I want to surround each line inside the tags with `li` tag and remove the popuplist tag. Could someone tell me how to do this? I can use jQuery, so that's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could search the TiddlyWiki HTML file for popuplist and wrap the line with the li tag by hand.  Then you search and replace the popuplist tag with an empty string to remove it throughout the document.

Comment: Please don't ask question in an answer. Ask question in the comment below the question.

Comment: I do not know how to ask questions below the original question.  I have two links below the question: "share" and "edit".

Comment: that's because you don't have enough reputation (the number below your user ID). But the goal here on StackOverflow is to give answer and not to interact like in a forum. You should edit your answer to remove unnescessary question or maybe change these question into suggestion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that might work for the wrapping: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5744244/258482

```
var x = $('#xxx').wrapAll('<div></div>').parent().html();
```

or

```
var x = $('#xxx').clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
```

If I remember right, I eventually went another route, like tiddly markup or something like that.