# Export SVG Element as SVG and PNG works on chrome but not firefox/safari

Tags: javascript, svg, export

I have a svg-element that I want to export as a SVG and PNG. There are already some approaches here on stack overflow, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218174/how-do-i-save-export-an-svg-file-after-creating-an-svg-with-d3-js-ie-safari-an) and the [one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6466603) from mbostock. However, I did 
something like this:

```
var $el = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="367" width="780"id="canvas" version="1.1" style="overflow: hidden;">
<circle r="12" style="cursor: move; fill: #4682b4; stroke: #000000; stroke-width: 1.5px;"/></svg>';

var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var res = serializer.serializeToString($el);

var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
hiddenElement.href = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(res);
hiddenElement.download = 'export.svg';
hiddenElement.click();
```

This does what it should do but only in chrome. Firefox does not react at all and safari tell me this:

> Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:8080".  The frame requesting access has a protocol
>   of "data", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http".
>   Protocols must match.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It seems you are using iframe or object don't you? Please provide the full code. `XMLSerializer().serializeToString()` works with appended DOM elements, you are passing an already string to it... Also, you don't need to encode as base64, just use `'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' +encodeURIComponent(res)`. Finally, your title talks about conversion to png. I assume you'll pass the dataURI to an `<img>`tag and then paint it on canvas to do so. There are caveats (basically external resources won't load). You can try to use this exporter I'm writing : https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG-to-Bitmap

Answer (score -1):

May be you are presenting your page a like `text/html`, use `application/xhtml+ xml`in `<head>` tag.`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; />`. Hope, it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately that doesn't work. So basically Im working on a Backbone View and I extract the svg through `$el.find('svg')`