# How can I ensure text is valid for an SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg

When I include a non-breaking space (character encoded as `\u00A0`) in an SVG `text` element, it works fine on a HTML page, but the resulting SVG contains an `&nbsp;` character and is therefore not valid as an SVG file. For example, if I save the SVG to a file (using a [function like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38019175/567595)) and open that file in Chrome, it reports an error "Entity 'nbsp' not defined" and does not display the text.

```js
const NS = { SVG: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" };
const svg = document.createElementNS(NS.SVG, 'svg');
const text = document.createElementNS(NS.SVG, "text");
text.setAttribute("y", 20);
const s = "Non-breaking> <space"; // the space here is a non-breaking one
text.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
svg.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(svg);
console.log(svg.outerHTML);
```

I can easily replace the problematic character with `s.replace("\u00A0", " ")`. But is there a more general way of sanitizing text going into an SVG to ensure it is valid and replacing the non-valid characters?

Comment: serve the HTML page as application/xhtml+xml rather than text/html

Comment: The &nbsp (non-breaking space) is used to create a space in a line that cannot be broken by word wrap. In SVG is not posible to breake the line. You can safely use a space here

Comment: or migrate/clone the contents you want to serialize (the SVG) so it's owned by an XMLDocument rather than a HTMLDocument.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, yes I think these suggestions would work. I initially didn't understand that generating the SVG in an HTML document was causing the unwanted character replacement and was trying to clean the individual text nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since svg recognizes only 5 html entities: `&amp;`, `&quot;`, `&apos;`, `&lt;`, and `&gt;`, we can filter out the rest:

```js
const NS = { SVG: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" };
const svg = document.createElementNS(NS.SVG, 'svg');
const text = document.createElementNS(NS.SVG, "text");
text.setAttribute("y", 20);
const s = "Non-breaking> <space & other\r\u0009characters"; // the space here is a non-breaking one

text.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
svg.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(svg);
console.log(svg.outerHTML);

saveSvg(svg, "test")

function saveSvg(svgEl, name) {
    svgEl.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
    const dummy = document.createElement("div");
    /* find all html entities and replace them with real value */
    var svgData = svgEl.outerHTML.replace(/(&(?!(amp|gt|lt|quot|apos))[^;]+;)/g, a =>
    {
      dummy.innerHTML = a;
      return dummy.textContent;
    });
    var preface = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>\r\n';
    var svgBlob = new Blob([preface, svgData], {type:"image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
    var svgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = svgUrl;
    downloadLink.download = name;
    downloadLink.textContent = "download";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
//    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```