# Export svg code to .svg file then upload local?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, potrace

My code:

```
var files = jQuery('#cargatulogo')[0].files;
Potrace.loadImageFromFile(files[0]);
Potrace.process(function () {
    svg = Potrace.getSVG(0.8);
    console.log(svg);
});
```

result console.log(svg):

[image]

I want to save it and upload it local.

Thanks.

Comment: create a file with svg format and open it with text editor and paste this console code.

Comment: It's simple enough to [export an SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23218877/519413), however it's not at all clear what you mean by 'upload local'.

Comment: after uploading the image to be converted to svg code format, i want to save that code as .svg file and upload to my folder

Comment: For future, it would be easier for people to help you if you didn't post an image.  Please put in some effort and copy, paste the text.