# Removing id attribute from HTML using jQuery/javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a mainWrap inside which content is populated dynamically.(It is somewhat like below)

```
          <div id="mainWrap">
                <div style="z-index: 1001; height: 407px; width: 328px; top: 150px; left: 601.5px;" id="com-TMRJDOR2KOET3X6JPV6XGU0FB7RGJ926" class="textBox contentBox">
                   <div style="" class="editable"><p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, </p>
                   </div>
                </div>

                <div style="z-index: 1002; height: 616px; width: 288px; top: 29px; left: 3.5px;" id="com-UPWTMKZ7OUTN8KG2JEK47LNPN5JO261H" class="textBox contentBox">
                   <div style="" class="editable"><p>
                ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
                  </div>
               </div>            
          </div>
```

The immediate children of `mainWrap` have an id attached to them.I want to **remove the ids** before I save it to the database.Now I have tried something like this

```
        var getContent = $('#mainWrap');  
        var finalContent =getContent.clone().find('*').removeAttr('id');// 1            
        var finalContent=getContent.clone().children().removeAttr('id');//2     
        alert(finalContent.html());
```

In both the cases I get the output as follows:

```
        <div style="" class="editable"><p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, </p>
        </div>
```

The outer div is removed and instead of two I get only 1 div.
But When I tried it out independently it works with the 2nd one.[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Qj826/) the fiddle

How can I get it right.I am not sure why its failing in the application and working independently!
Thank you for the time

Comment: There is a `</div>` too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try be more specific in parents selection .

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var getContent = $('#mainWrap');
    var finalContent = $('div.textBox', getContent).clone();

    finalContent.each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('id');
    });
    console.log(finalContent[0]);
});
```

See it here http://jsbin.com/ewosix/1/

```
 $('button').click(function () {
     var newContent = $(finalContent).first().wrap('<div class="addId" />');
     newContent = $(newContent).parents( /*You can add specific selector for parents like div.textBox or leave it emty for all parents */ ).each(function (index, value) {
         $(this).attr('id', index);
     });
     alert($(newContent).html());
 });
```

Comment: To see what is printed open your browser console!
For instance in Chrome or Safari is F12 key

Comment: I cannot use classes as they won't be the same each time.hence I tried it with `$('div', getContent).clone();` earlier.But when I do a `console.log(finalContent[0]);` I see the right output,but if I do a `alert(finalContent.html());` I get the output in my question.Why this?

Comment: Because you see the `innerHTML` of the outer `textbox` div.
This is what `.html()` does returns the inner HTML. Wrap both and get the parent html

Comment: So if I do `alert(finalContent.parent.html())` will it give me the entire stuff?Please correct if wrong,still learning jquery! :P

Comment: If you `alert(finalContent.parent().html())` you'll get the inner html of `body` which is `mainWrap`and its children
The entire stuff it is

Comment: Yup!!!Well..neever new this thing!! `console.log([0])` saved my life and offcourse you!Spend so much time for a stupid mistake!! :PThank you very much!Accepted and upvoted! :)

Comment: If we are following I need one more help!! How can I get the HTML of the outer most div.(In mycase `#mainWrap`).I want the main or outer most div also with the id's removed.

Comment: If you want the outer HTML you do that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html
Follow this example  just change the `#xxx` selector with the selector of your most outer div `#mainWrap`
If you want the inner HTML as ususal `$('#mainWrap').html()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but to remove id's of immediate children of `#mainWrap` div, you can use following code:

`$('#mainWrap > *').removeAttr('id');`

Comment: It won't be divs every time!!Hence I tried using children as I wanted them to be removed for all the children of mainWrap.

Comment: Looks like you can use * selector (I've try it in sample document). I've update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `each`

You can find useful help [**each jquery**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
finalContent.each(function()
{
    $(this).removeAttr('id')
})
```

Because finalContent is object with more than one dom.

Comment: When I do this I get the output same as in the question if I alert and  correct output when I do `console.log(finalContent[0]);` Please see my comment to @Kidwon's answer

Comment: Thank you!Got it to work!You have been a helpful guy for me!!Kudos!Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/AKC9u/) is the fiddle. I think this is what you are looking for

Here is the js code:

```
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
     $("#wrap").children('div').each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('id');
     });
   alert($("#wrap").html());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the solution for your problem:

```
var mainWrap = $('#mainWrap').clone();
mainWrap.children().removeAttr('id');

alert(mainWrap.html());
```