# Outputting html tags as text in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
 Image height: <input type="text" id="imgHeight" /><br /><br />
 Image width:  <input type="text" id="imgWidth" /><br /><br />
 Number of images: <input type="text" id="imgNo" /><br /><br />
    <input type="button" value="Show code" id="result" /><br /><br />

    <textarea rows="20" cols="60" id="output"></textarea>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#result").click(function(){
            var imgHeight = $("#imgHeight").val();
            var imgWidth = $("#imgWidth").val();
            var imgNo = $("#imgNo").val();
            for(i=0; i<imgNo; i++){
                $("#output").text("<img src='' width='"+imgHeight+"' height='"+imgWidth+"' />");
            }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

What I'd like to do is to be able to output the html code as plain text to the textarea (I'd like people to be able to copy the generated code). I'd like the img tag to be shown in the text area as many times as I have specified in the "Number of images" box. The code above outputs the code as text only once regardless of the "Number of images" I type in.
Can you help me with that?
Thx in advance 
**[EDIT]**
Thank you very much for your fast responses
Now I'm stuck with something different. I want users to be able to put their own links and I want those links to appear in the textarea within each image tag created. However, I cannot think a way to "grab" the content of each input and put it in the  tag. It always shows the content of the first input
Any help, please? :)
Here's the code:

```
 Image height: <input type="text" id="imgHeight" /><br /><br />
 Image width:  <input type="text" id="imgWidth" /><br /><br />
 Number of images: <input type="text" id="imgNo" /><br /><br />
 <p id="additionalImgs"></p>
    <input type="button" value="Show code" id="result" onclick="abba()" /><br /><br />  
    <textarea rows="20" cols="60" id="output"></textarea>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#result").click(function(){
            var imgHeight = $("#imgHeight").val();
            var imgWidth = $("#imgWidth").val();
            var imgNo = $("#imgNo").val();
            var text = '';
            var y = 1;
            for(i=0; i<imgNo; i++){
            var aaa = $("#additionalImgs input").val();
            text += "<img src='"+aaa +"' width='"+imgHeight+"' height='"+imgWidth+"' name='"+ y++ +"' />";
}
$('#output').text(text);

            });
        });
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#imgNo").change(function(){
                var imgNo = $("#imgNo").val();
                x = 1;
                var y = 1;
                var text = "Image number: ";
                for(i=0; i<imgNo; i++){
                $("#additionalImgs").append(text + y++ + ' link' + "<input type='text' name='"+ x++  +"'><br />")};
                });
            });

    </script>
```

Comment: that's because you overwitre the contents of the textarea with each .text() call, so you get only the last image's html.

Comment: I think you're supposed to mark the answer as correct and then ask a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text()` overwrites the current text in the element. 
You could use `.append()` or append the text to  a variable and apply that variable with `.text()` after the for loop:

```
var text = '';
for(i=0; i<imgNo; i++){
    text += "<img src='' width='"+imgHeight+"' height='"+imgWidth+"' />";
}
$('#output').text(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to append the text, in each iteration it sets the text, it is not appending.
Change your loop body as follows:

```
txt=$("#output").text();
$("#output").text( txt + "<img src='' width='"+imgHeight+"' height='"+imgWidth+"' />");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the "outer HTML" of the IMG tag and put it in a textbox like this:

```
var html = $('<div>').append($('#imageID').clone()).html();
$("#textboxID").val(html);
```

This is based on Box9's answer at: [jQuery: outer html()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html)

See demo at JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VUbfh/1/