# Jquery .html() how to get all html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this JQuery to create some elements:

```
var form = $(document.createElement("form"));
form.prop({"action":"/DoSomething", "method": "POST"});
var input = $(document.createElement("input"));
input.prop({"type": "image", "src": "someUrl.png"});
form.append(input);
```

I now want to get the entire html string that is generated by all that so:

```
<form action="/DoSomething" method="POST"><input type="image" src="someUrl.Png" /></form>
```

So that I can pass it through some other Javascript functions!

However, doing `form.html()` obviously only shows this:

```
<input type="image" src="someUrl.Png" />
```

So how do you get all the html?

***EDIT***

Yeah I can see that this is a duplicate, when I first wrote it, I had no idea what I was trying to achieve or the atleast the name given to what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Use `$(document).html()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`form.wrap('<div />').parent().html()`

to work across all browsers or

`form[0].outerHTML`

if you don't really care about older Firefox versions (< 11)

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

Create a temporary element, then `clone()` and `append()`:

```
$('<div>').append($('#xxx').clone()).html();
```

See more answers [here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html)

Answer (score 0):

check out this

```
form[0]
```

you need the element it self not wrapped version  so just use the index 0

Comment: This returns the element, not its HTML string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var outer_html = $('selector').clone().wrap('<p>').parent().html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the DOM element, rather than a jQuery object, and get `outerHTML`...

In your code it would be...

```
form[0].outerHTML;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ugyS/1/

Answer (score -1):

Just use the containg element of form

```
form.parent().html()
```

Comment: Take into accoun that your answer may add other items to the html.