# Get the TABLE outerHTML by ID attributes JQUERY

Tags: jquery, html

is there a way to get the outerHTML of the element TABLE using ID attributes?

Example HTML:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
     <body>
       <table id="mytable">
           <tr>
               <td>Some Data</td>
           </tr>
       </table>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: just edited the sample html above. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html

Comment: I will remodify the question again.. but I guess this sample answered my question enough.

Comment: you don't need to change your question. In the future, before you ask a question, use the search to see if your question has already been asked. Search for `get outer html jquery` in Stack Overflow and you will find great answers to your question.

Comment: i guess i mixed up the question to the answers im looking for.. but i have posted another question which is very clear to my problem.. those who have answered this question is really a great help tho.

Comment: this should be the question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508708/conditional-statement-that-check-the-table-id-asp-xml-dom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without jquery

```
document.getElementById('mytable').outerHTML
```

like

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <table id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <td>Some Data</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        var html = document.getElementById('mytable').outerHTML;
        alert(html)
    </script>
</html>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0IXm6mlAlAbUSgqqJ4GY?p=preview)

jQuery does not have a method to fetch the outHTML of an element, so again you need to get hold of the dom element reference

```
$('#mytable')[0].outerHTML
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cDCETLvAOBH8Ge4Sz7xk?p=preview)

Comment: or how about DOM? like getting the table via ID?

Comment: i have this html stored on the variable and im trying to create a conditional statement that looks on the table id.. i have the sample code here to show you how it is work.. it is written in ASP.

html is stored on variable `responseText` 

    For Each table In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
        If table.className = "results" Then
   tablestr = table.outerHTML
   Session("isEmpty") = false
 End If
    Next

Comment: is there a way to create a conditional statement like this? this code is filtered through className identifier. how about through its ID?