# jquery DOM accessing parent element

Tags: jquery

I need to access to tr element in table.

I have 3 colums and in last column have checkbox. In event on change I have code:

`alert( $(this).parent().parent().html() );`

Which get all 3 td elements, but I need it with tr parent tag.

I tried:

`alert( $(this).parent().parent().parent().html() );`

`alert( $(this).parent().parent().prev().html() );`

And doesn't work.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
   <thead bgcolor="#668c41">
      <tr>
         <th>App</th>
         <th>Server</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="dialog-app">
      <tr>
         <td>appA</td>
         <td>serverA</td>
         <td><input checked="" type="checkbox"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you share your html too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: outer html()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html)

Comment: <table>
<thead bgcolor="#668c41">
  <tr><th>App</th><th>Server</th><th>Action</th></tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="dialog-app"><tr><td>appA</td>
<td>serverA</td>
<td><input checked="" type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>

Comment: Try `alert( $(this).closest('tr').prop('outerHTML') );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** instead:

```
alert( $(this).closest('tr').html() );
```

If you want the outer HTML which is your closest `tr` element as well, then you can do:

```
alert($(this).closest('tr')[0].outerHTML)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to reach the closest enclosing `tr` , you can use `closest()`

`$(this).closest('tr')[0].outerHTML`  `// to get html including the tr`

`---->`  http://api.jquery.com/closest/