# How to get parent as well as child's html in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<ul class="messages">
<li class="error-msg">
    <ul>
        <li><span>Error.</span></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>

 $(document).ready(function(){
    if($("ul.messages").length > 0){
        var MessageContent = $("ul.messages").html();
        alert(MessageContent);
    }
});
```

Above jquery code alert inner `li` of `ul` having class `messages`.
I want entire html but in reference with class `messages`.

[fiddle here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/J9TVg/)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("ul.messages").length > 0){
        var MessageContent = $("ul.messages")[0].outerHTML;
        alert(MessageContent);
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/J9TVg/2/)