# Adding a class to images of a dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am loading a content dynamically. The content is in html form and I need to get all of it's images and add a class to them. This is what I have done:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
console.log($(jsonObj.content).find("img").addClass("img-responsive"));
document.getElementById("myModalContent").innerHTML = jsonObj.content;
```

The console shows me that a class has been added but the DOM doesn't have that class. Why is it happening?

Comment: I don't get what the question is. Can you elaborate? How did you check the DOM doesn't have the class?

Comment: Pay attention: IE don't show you most of the DOM manipulations done. It give just the DOM sended by the server.

Comment: @putvande I am trying to add a class to the images of the `html` response returned from an AJAX call. When I log it into the console, it shows me a class has been added but the DOM doesn't have that class on the images. Why?

Comment: because you add class to jsonObj. And I don't see that you add your jsonObj to the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually creating a new object, add the classes and then, change the innerHTML with the old string. You should change it for the new object html :

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
var $el = $(jsonObj.content).find("img").addClass("img-responsive").end();
document.getElementById("myModalContent").innerHTML = $el.prop('outerHTML');
```

Or even better :

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
var $el = $(jsonObj.content).find("img").addClass("img-responsive").end();
$("#myModalContent").append($el);
```

Comment: I think there is no `jQuery.outterHTML` method :)

Comment: @drinchev those damn typos!

Comment: But still. Even `outerHTML`. jQuery specs doesn't provide you this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html

Comment: @drinchev You're right, that method is in my file only.

Comment: Now the content is not appended on the modal :/

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui edited the answer, tell me if it work.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon The images are removed now. :'(

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui oh great! I was gonna ask for a fiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't capture the jQuery object.

You should do something like this :

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
var $Obj = $(jsonObj.content).find("img").addClass("img-responsive").end();
document.getElementById("myModalContent").innerHTML = $Obj[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: I think you need to add `.end()`