# Selecting all content from sub elements of a div

Tags: jquery

If I have a `div` element like so:

```
<div id="someContents">
    <p>Foo has the following properties</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Bar</li>
    </ul>
    <p>And some other stuff</p>
</div>
```

And declare this:

```
var $someContents = $('#someContents');
```

Then I want to declare a now var which will be a single `String` and will have the contents that you see on screen with line breaks etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/7a5b9/

I have tried various JQuery methods... Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You mean like this: `var now = $(someContents).find('*').text();`

Comment: @ThinkDifferent that's the one... I knew there would be a simple way to do it with JQuery but just couldn't think of the method. Post as answer and I will accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var now = $(someContents).find('*').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $someContents = $('#someContents').html();
alert($someContents);
```

**This gets all of the HTML content and yields:**

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/dFB3J/

---

```
var $someContents = $('#someContents').text();
alert($someContents);
```

**This gets all of the inner text content and yields:**

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/z2f26/

---

```
(function($){
   $.fn.innerText = function(msg) {
         if (msg) {
            if (document.body.innerText) {
               for (var i in this) {
                  this[i].innerText = msg;
               }
            } else {
               for (var i in this) {
                  this[i].innerHTML.replace(/&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;/gi,"n").replace(/(&amp;lt;([^&amp;gt;]+)&amp;gt;)/gi, "");
               }
            }
            return this;
         } else {
            if (document.body.innerText) {
               return this[0].innerText;
            } else {
               return this[0].innerHTML.replace(/&amp;lt;br&amp;gt;/gi,"n").replace(/(&amp;lt;([^&amp;gt;]+)&amp;gt;)/gi, "");
            }
         }
   };
})(jQuery);

var $someContents = $('#someContents').innerText();
alert($someContents);
```

**This gets all of the inner text content (preserving line breaks) and yields:**

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/4gpLE/

<sub>Source: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-text-function/</sub>

Comment: no guy, this only takes the inner content of the tag. He also needs the parent tag text (the div #someContents)

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html)

A simple way is to create a temporary clone of your html, put it inside another tag and get the `text` or `html` content.

```
$('<div>').append($('#xxx').clone()).html();
```