# Get the text of a DOM <script> tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

So I have this block of html code:

```
<div id="widget-injection">
   <script id="metamorph-15-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
   <div id="ember977" class="ember-view widget-content">
     ...
   </div>
   <script id="metamorph-15-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script><script id="metamorph-10-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>

   ...(more widgets with the same structure as above)
</div>
```

Inside my div "widget-injection" I have multiple widgets. I iterate over each one with this to get their html:

```
this.$(".widget-content").each(function(i){
   console.log($(this).prev()[0]);//It prints the correct string that I want "<script id="meta..."
   widgetsHtml.push($(this).prev()[0]+$(this).html()+$(this).next()[0]);                
 });
```

It works fine inside widget-content, although, if you notice I get each prev() and next() element which are ember.js notation scripts that surrounds every widget. That is the part that doesn't work. I want to append those prev() and next() strings to the string that results from $(this).html() (which is each widget-content HTML). Although, I always end up getting "[object HTMLScriptElement]" instead of `"<script id="meta..."` from my prev() and next() elements when what I want is simply the correspondent string. So my question is, how do I convert an element which is a DOM script to purely text/string?

PS: If I have a `<script id="meta...">` inside widget-content it ends up being converted correctly to text.

EDIT: I forgot to say that I tried everything else from html(), text(), val(), innerText, innerHTML, you name it. I always got empty string or undefined.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you have already done it with $(this). By using [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

.prev[0] gets you the DOM element.

So in your case:

```
$(this).prev().html()+$(this).html()+$(this).next().html()
```

if you don't want content, but the actual tags, you'll have to use [outerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html/5744268#5744268):

```
$(this).prev()[0].outerHTML + $(this)[0].outerHTML + $(this).next()[0].outerHTML
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I tried everything else html() text() val() you name it. I always got empty string or undefined.

Comment: @JoãoMartins I'm not familiar with ember.js. Is your example the actual html, or what's inside the script tag? Cause right now they are empty.

Comment: There's nothing inside the script. It's just a place that ember uses to know where are the binded elements I guess. So, it's just <script id="metamorph-15-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>

Comment: @JoãoMartins oh, ok. I updated my answer. .html() only returns the content of the tag, so you have to use outerHTML

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".widget-content").each(function(i){
    console.log($(this).prev());//It prints the correct string that I want "<script id="meta..."
    // get div html
    var getthishtml = $(this).html();
    // empty this div html
    $(this).html();
    // move prev script inside div 
    $($(this).prev()).prependTo(widgetsHtml);
    // append div html
    $(this).append(getthishtml );
    // move next script inside div
    $($(this).next()).prependTo(widgetsHtml);   
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rLjdqvo3/) you can check inspent elements to get the result

Comment: I forgot to say that I tried everything else html() text() val() you name it. I always got empty string or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the plain text of the script tag:
http://jsfiddle.net/ef93x2aq/

```
var script = documenet.getElementById('metamorph-15-start');
var text = script.innerText;
document.write(text);
```