# jQuery Cloning Parent Element

Tags: jquery, clone

I'm wanting to clone a parent element. Currently I've only managed to clone the contents of that element.

```
$(this).parents('.row').clone();
```

This returns the contents of .row, how may I clone the .row element?

[Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/vozesulasu/1/edit?html,js,console,output) - give the last input a value

Comment: `var copylast = self.parents('.row').clone()` ?

Comment: I left out setting the variable as I thought it was pointless fluff to the question.

Comment: [Maybe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you don't include is that you're using `.html()` in your jsbin code, which is what's actually returning the inner part of the row.

To "combat" this, use a temporary container and do the `.html()` on the container:

```
$('<div>').append($(this).parents('.row').clone()).html();
```

http://jsbin.com/fesicaqotu/1/edit?js,output

Another, perhaps better option, is to use `.outerHTML` on the dom element and forget the clone altogether:

```
self.parents('.row')[0].outerHTML;
```

http://jsbin.com/buhekitiju/2/edit?js,output

Comment: Digging deeper, it appears the actual issue is that I'm editing the cloned variable, when I do: .find('input').empty().end().html() - it removes the container element. Is there a way to manipulate the cloned variable without losing the container element?

Comment: Are you trying to clear the value? Use `.find('input').val('')`. [`.empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) removes nodes belonging to the selected elements, and `input` element have no children. So that's not the issue. With `.html()`, you are still going to get what's inside the selected element, not what's inside wrapped with what's the wrapper included (this is called `outerHTML`, `.html()` is `.innerHTML`, see my edit).

Comment: I see. So something like: var copylast = self.parents('.row')[0].outerHTML.find('input').val(''); ?

Comment: `outerHTML` is going to give you a string. Do `$(self.parents('.row')[0].outerHTML).find('.input').val('').end();` The alternative would be to do the latter in a separate call, `var copyLast = $(self.parents('.row')[0].outerHTML); copyLast.find('.input').val('');`

Comment: Neither of those methods are working, unless I'm doing it wrong? http://jsbin.com/pecehulafo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: You have a typo on the line where you append the `copyLast` node (hint: the console tells you why).