# Div tag code extractor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to have a button that when clicked it will extract the whole code within a specific div tag? Is it possible in javescript, jquery, or php?

Say for example:

```
<div class="extactMe">
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><img src="icon.png"></a>
</div>
```

If I click the button "Extract" on the web page for example, the whole div tag from `<div class="extactMe">` to `</div>` will be copied to a textarea. Please advise thank you.

Comment: here is your path to solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html

Comment: PHP is server side so not via PHP; or not without a round-about solution involving AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `outerHTML` property. Try this:

```
var divHtml = $('.extractMe').prop('outerHTML');
$('textarea').val(divHtml);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4bywLvqr/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
var extracted = $('.extractMe').html();
```

Comment: Note that this will only get the `a` element inside the `div`.

Comment: The "$('.extractMe').prop('outerHTML');" did the trick but the solution you gave is something I can use in the future so thank you as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Full example over at JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jo37u3xs/

PHP is not involved here.

The Javascript part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // when you click the button
    $("#button-extract").click( function() {

        // get the html of the div
        var divContent = $('div.extractMe').html();

        // insert the html of the div into the textarea
        $("textarea#my-textarea").val(divContent);        
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="extractMe">
   <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><img src="icon.png">Yo, man. The image is missing.</a><br/>
</div>

<br/>    

<button type="button" id="button-extract">Extract</button>

<br/><br/>   

 <textarea cols="50" rows="10" id="my-textarea">
Its empty at the start. Err, not really.
</textarea>
```

Please look the following jQuery functions up to understand what they do:

- .click()
- .html()
- .val()
- and jQuery Selectors: $(".class") and $("#id")

Comment: amazing, yes I will surely do look on to those topics, thank you so much ya'll guys I really appreciate it. Thank you for giving the complete code. Bookmarking it now :) case solved.