# how to get the hrml tags one by one using HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to get the entire html of a selected element not just it's `contents. .html()` uses javascripts `innerHTML()` method according to the documentation. HTML:

```
  <div id="div1">
    <p>Some Content</p>
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </div>
```

Using `$("#div1").html()`. its returned hole content of div tags

```
<p>Some Content</p>
<p>Some Content</p>
```

I can't use . i need one by one p tags, How to get this using each statement. Any one please help.

Comment: I got it from first google result. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you need "<p>Some Content</p>" or "Some Content"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all children's and iterate over them. Html content can be get from [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property of dom element.

```js
// for older browser compatibility use [].slice.call instead of Array.from
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#div1 p')).forEach(function(ele) {
  console.log(ele.outerHTML);
})
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <p>Some Content</p>
  <p>Some Content</p>
</div>
```

---

With jQuery using [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method.

```js
$('#div1 p').each(function() {
  console.log(this.outerHTML);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <p>Some Content</p>
  <p>Some Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need `.html()`, you need `.children()`.

```
$('#div1').children().each(function (index, childEl) {
  console.log(childEl);
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: Why the downvote?  It's very clear he wants the children of an element, and he's using jQuery so this answer is appropriate.  If you're going to downvote a perfectly acceptable answer, you should really explain why.