# Get HTML content by outerHTML and remove one div

Tags: jquery, html, outerhtml

I am getting content of HTML tag by using `outerHTML`

```
var t=$("html")[0].outerHTML;
```

but I need to remove a specific div from result

```
<div id="admin_panel">...</div>
```

here is my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#save').click(function(){
        var t=$("html")[0].outerHTML;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save.php",
            data: { code: t },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                alert('Changed saved');
            }
        });
    })
});
```

How do I remove the div correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that:

```
$(function() {
    $('#save').click(function(){
        var t = $("html")[0].outerHTML;
        var $t = $(t);
        $t.find("#admin_panel").remove();
        t = $t[0].outerHTML;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save.php",
            data: { code: t },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                alert('Changed saved');
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: oops! fixed the answer. try this

Answer (score 0):

Non-destructive:

[jQuery: outer html()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html)

```
var $div = $('<div/>').append($('html').clone()).html();
$div.find("#admin-panel").remove();
var t=$div.html();
```