# Get jQuery object back into string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, parsing

Making an object (or something?) from a string:

```
var thing = $.parseHTML("<h1>Some HTML</h1>"); // i.e., from $("#something").html()
```

Converting it back into a string?

```
$(thing).html(); // doesn't work
undefined
$(thing).get(0).outerHTML; // doesn't work
undefined
$(thing).outerHTML; // doesn't work
undefined
$(thing).get(0).html(); // doesn't work
undefined
```

What's the inverse of `$.parseHTML()`? I just want to modify some HTML and put it back where I got it.

Comment: And this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5744246/2375207

Comment: thing = $(thing).get(0).outerHTML; works for me.
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/61241/ check this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert jQuery object to string, you can use `.prop('outerHTML')`, like:

```js
var thing = $.parseHTML("<h1>Some HTML</h1>");
var original = $(thing).prop('outerHTML');

console.log( original );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Seems like a roundabout way to do it. Why not `thing[0].outerHTML`

Comment: Well, we dont really know OP's whole code. This can be used if the object is already a jQuery object which I stated on my answer. There are always multiple ways to skin the cat :)

Comment: Wonder if this has changed in newer versions of jquery. Does not work for me - $(thing).prop('outerHTML'); returns undefined

Answer (score 1):

Check its `outerHTML`

```
console.log( thing[0].outerHTML );
```

**Demo**

```js
var thing = $.parseHTML("<h1>Some HTML</h1>"); 

console.log( thing[0].outerHTML );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```