# jQuery ignoring initial html element created when calling html()

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create table elements using jQuery but it won't return the first element stored or created:

```
$("<tr>",{class: "ertert"}).append($("<td>",{text:"adfsadfasdf"})).html()

// "<td>adfsadfasdf</td>"
```

What happened to the `<tr>`?

Comment: `.html()` retrieves the _inner_ HTML, not the outer HTML. Why do you need to get the outer HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: outer html()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744207/jquery-outer-html)

Comment: In case you *really* want the outer HTML you should replace `.html()` with `[0].outerHTML`. This will get the outerHTML property of the first created DOM element of your jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:
HTML:

```
<table class="parent"></table>
```

JS:

```
$('.parent').html('<tr class="name"><td>anything</td></tr>');
```

if you do not want to replace use this to add:

```
$('.parent').append('<tr class="name"><td>anything</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

When chaining it with `html()` method at the end, it only returns outer HTML for the `<tr>`. You have not assigned `<tr>` to any of variable & nor you have added it to DOM yet, hence it is no longer accessible. You have lost it in the local scope.
If you use a variable such that

```
var $tr = $("<tr>",{class: "ertert"});
$tr.append($("<td>",{text:"adfsadfasdf"})).html()
```

You will be able to access it again.